# arithmetic overflow error for type varchar value =770214566.000000000

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, winforms, datagridview

I have a dtatgridview in which data are assigned from excel sheet and a button that insert the rows from dtatgridview into sql server table , the error occurs when I click the insert button and gives me the exception as declared in my question title above the value 770214566 is the the mobile number of a user and its data type is char(9) in my table this is my code for the insert button:

```
private void addCarsSaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < addCarsDgv.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into cars(Id,name,carType,stickerNo,plotNo,carPath,mobile,whats) values (@id,@name,@type,@sticker,@plot,@path,@mobile,@whats)", cn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id + i);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sticker", Convert.ToInt32(addCarsDgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", addCarsDgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", addCarsDgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@whats", addCarsDgv.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", addCarsDgv.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plot", addCarsDgv.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", addCarsDgv.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("All Done!");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Quite simple - **DON'T USE ADDWITHVALUE** [because bad](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, `AddWithValue` will interpret your intent correctly.  In cases like this, however, when it does not, you can always give it a helping hand by either:

- Casting the datatype to force the context to match.  In your example, a simple `.ToString()` might do the trick...  then again if those decimals are really there, I can see another error coming your way.  This is not bulletproof, as you can tell.  Another example of where this might fail is how timestamps and dates both cast to the C# `DateTime` datatype
- Being explicit about the datatype of the parameter.  Unless you do something irrational (like put a character into a numeric field) that causes an error anyway, this should be bulletproof

Here is an example of how to implement option #2:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", addCarsDgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
cmd.Parameters[3].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char;
```

This may go without saying, but the "[3]" is because it's the fourth parameter.

Or, as others have suggested, don't use `AddWithValue`.